# How to get a more informative assertion when using assertr::verify in R?

Tags: r, debugging, verify, assertr

```
meses <- c("A", "B", "C")

tibble::tibble(
  mes = c("A", "b", "C")
) %>% 
  assertr::verify(mes %in% meses)
```

message from `verify`. It's correct as it says the error's index but in the `value` column does not show the value of the `mes` column from the `tibble` so I have to look for the row.

```
    verb redux_fn      predicate column index value
1 verify       NA mes %in% meses     NA     2    NA
```

desired output

```
    verb redux_fn      predicate column index value
1 verify       NA mes %in% meses     NA     2    b
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `assert` to return the 'value'

```
library(assertr)
library(tibble)
tibble(mes = c("A", "b", "C")) %>% 
   assert(function(x)  x %in% meses, mes)
Column 'mes' violates assertion 'function(x) x %in% meses' 1 time
    verb redux_fn                predicate column index value
1 assert       NA function(x) x %in% meses    mes     2     b
```

---

With `verify`, the default option in `error_fun` is `error_stop`.  If we can change the default option, it should work

```
tibble::tibble(
  mes = c("A", "b", "C")
) %>% 
  assertr::verify(mes %in% meses, 
  error_fun = function(errors, data = .) 
   {
     errors[[1]]$error_df$value <- .$mes[errors[[1]]$error_df$index]
   errors[[1]]
  })
```

-output

```
verification [mes %in% meses] failed! (1 failure)

    verb redux_fn      predicate column index value
1 verify       NA mes %in% meses     NA     2     b
```

Comment: Can you use more than one variable from the data when using `assert`? and how would you customize the `value` ?

Comment: @AlvaroMorales yes it is a variadic argument.  So you can use multiple columns i.e. `assert(mtcars, not_na, mpg:carb)` (from example documentation).  Here the `not_na` is a function that returns `(!is.na(x)) | is.nan(x)` which is applied to all those columns

Comment: You can check with `mtcars$mpg[2] <- NA;mtcars$carb[5] <- NA;assert(mtcars, not_na, mpg:carb)`

Comment: @AlvaroMorales for your example, it would be `tibble(mes = c("A", "b", "C"), mes2 = c("D", "a", "B")) %>% 
   assert(function(x)  x %in% meses, mes, mes2)`

Comment: Sorry I mean two variables in the predicate function. something like this:
`tibble(mes = c("A", "b", "C"), mes2 = c(10, 50, 100)) %>% assertr::assert(function(x, y) x %in% meses & y > 50, mes, mes2)`